# Is there a way to boot Linux on the onboard graphics, and Windows on my Graphics Card?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, windows, nvidia, intel

I will admit, I am kind of a noob when it comes to Linux. I am TRYING to get better, but to get better, I kind of need to install Linux, instead of running it on the RAM disk however, I am not ready to have an all Linux machine. Is there a way I can have a monitor plugged into my onboard graphics, and run Linux, but also plug a monitor into my graphics card, and run Windows 10? Here are my computer specs.

CPU: [Intel Core i7-2600K](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52214/intel-core-i7-2600k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html)

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti

RAM: 8GB Corsair Vengence

PSU: OCZ 750W

Motherboard: ASUS P8Z68-V PRO/GEN3

I would like to install Linux Mint. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your motherboard?

Comment: Hello Alex, I think what you are dreaming of is the idea of running two operating systems on one computer at the same time. This is not a realistic option. However you can achieve the same effect if your willing to run some of your operating systems on a virtual machine. A free-ish virtual machine i'm aware of is VirtualBox, maybe try that out :)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use virtualbox on windows (or vice versa)

Give virtualbox exclusive access to the onboard graphics (basically have
virtualbox give exclusive access to a virtual machine which runs linux.)

Comment: Will this work if his CPU does not support VT-d? For, that's the case with his Intel Core i7-2600K

Comment: Alright, I tried VirtualBox, but I can't find where to add onboard graphics to the VM.